# MYSQL return null when more rows than IN values

Tags: mysql, sql, messaging, where-in

I'm having trouble finding a right title for this.

I'm working on a messaging system with two tables, one with all the different conversations (users in conversation and uid of the conversation) and one that contains the messages between the users.

For each conversation I'm creating a row for every user in the conversation with the uid of the conversation and the user_id. In conversations there can be just 2 users but also many more (3,4,5,6 etc.)

I'm having a problem with my SQL statement that I don't know how to solve. The problem is when lets say that there is a conversation between 3 user, after that lets say that 2 of the users want to start talking to each other in private without the 3rd user. How can I make the SQL statement return nothing when the 2 users are already in a conversation together with other users. So that I can add 2 new rows in my table with their own private conversation_id.

the `conversation_list` table looks like this :

```
|id | user_id| conversation_id|
 -----------------------------
| 1 |       1|               1|
| 2 |       3|               1|
| 3 |       1|               2|
| 4 |       2|               2|
| 5 |       4|               2|
```

And for now my SQL code is like this :

```
SELECT *
FROM conversation_list
WHERE user_id IN (user1_id,user_id2)
GROUP BY conversation_id
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
```

Comment: What's wrong with the SQL you're currently using?

Comment: how about having count(*) > 2 ?

Comment: @Gerrat if I add `COUNT(*) > 2` it returns nothing even if the two rows where just added, in which case it should return the conversation_id of the row previously inserted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Is this restatement of your question correct:*

**"How can I make the SQL statement return nothing when any of the two users are in a conversation with any other users"?**

...or

**"How can I make the SQL statement return rows ONLY when these users are NOT in a conversation with other users?"**

```
SELECT conversation_id
FROM conversation_list
WHERE user_id IN (5,6)
AND conversation_id NOT IN (
    SELECT conversation_id from conversation_list where user_id NOT IN (5,6)
)
GROUP BY conversation_id
HAVING COUNT(*) = :nb_users
```

This should only return rows if these users are NOT in a conversation with other users.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works really good. I just added `GROUP BY conversation_id HAVING COUNT(*) = :nb_users `

Comment: And this is the correct question : "How can I make the SQL statement return nothing when any of the two users are in a conversation with any other users"

Answer (score 1):

Let's see if I understood your problem correctly: You want to return the `conversation_id` only if you've listed all the `user_id`s that participate in that conversation?

If that is the case, take a look at my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5479975/query-for-a-set-in-a-relational-database/5480412#5480412). You can think of the conversations as named sets of participants, so the `conversation_id` is the name of the set and the `user_id`s are the items of that set. The answer has 3 different ways of doing it, with explanations included.

The last version, adapted to your table, would be roughly like:

```
SELECT totals.conversation_id
FROM (
    SELECT conversation_id, COUNT(*) count
    FROM conversation_list
    GROUP BY conversation_id
) totals
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT conversation_id, COUNT(*) count
    FROM conversation_list
    WHERE user_id IN (6, 5)
    GROUP BY conversation_id
) matches
ON (totals.conversation_id = matches.conversation_id)
WHERE totals.count = 2 AND matches.count = 2;
```

Where 6 and 5 are the `user_id`s and 2 is the number of `user_id`s.

The first subquery finds the total count of users in each conversation and the second one finds out the count of matching users in each conversation. When `matches.count` is 2, the conversation has all the users we're looking for, and if `totals.count` is also 2, the conversation doesn't have any extra users.