# How to model unique sets in relational database (sqlite)

Tags: android, database, sqlite, set

I'm working on an android application (so must use sqlite) and I've been searching around for a good way to model a Java Set (i.e. `HashSet`) in a relational database.  Initially, I figured it would be two tables with a many-to-many relationship:

```
table name: sets
    _id integer (PK)

table name: fruits
    _id integer (PK)
    name varchar (unique, so alternate key)

table name: fruit_sets
    set_id (FK)    // combination key to prevent
    fruit_id (FK)  // duplicate fruits in each set
```

So in this db model I'm pretty sure it can support relationships like:

```
[ apple, orange, pear ] != [ apple, orange, grape, pear ]
```

but,

```
[ apple, orange, pear ] == [ pear, apple, orange ]
```

So, if I have in the database:

```
set 1 = [ apple, orange ]
set 2 = [ orange, pear, apple ]
set 3 = [ grape, pear ]
set 4 = [ grape, orange, apple, cherry ]
```

I was struggling with a good way to `select` a set_id when I am given a set in Java.  So, for example if I have in Java, the HashSet: `[ apple, orange, pear ]`, how would I structure a `select` query for a `set_id`?

should return `set_id` of: 2

...or is there a different and better way to model this kind of relationship?

Comment: I found my answer here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5479975/query-for-a-set-in-a-relational-database?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

It is only concept, but I think the idea is clear

```
SELECT DISTINCT set_id FROM fruit_sets
WHERE set_id IN (
SELECT DISTINCT set_id FROM fruit_sets WHERE fruit_id = (SELECT _id FROM fruits WHERE name = myHashSet.size().iterator().next)
INTERSECT
SELECT DISTINCT set_id FROM fruit_sets WHERE fruit_id = (SELECT _id FROM fruits WHERE name = myHashSet.size().iterator().next)
INTERSECT
SELECT DISTINCT set_id FROM fruit_sets WHERE fruit_id = (SELECT _id FROM fruits WHERE name = myHashSet.size().iterator().next)
)
GROUP BY set_id HAVING COUNT(*) = myHashSet.size()
```